# Use http request that calls pixabay api to display images in Angular 6

Tags: angular, api, http

I want to show a list of images that i get from an api called pixabay, using http request works fine in angular 4, what is the proper way using angular 6 :

```
   pagePhoto:any;

   onSearch(dataForm){
       this.http.get("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=10727287-66f9e40c95980a4fc92c26b12&q="+dataForm.motCle+"&per_page=5&page=1")
       .map(resp=>resp.json())
       .subscribe(data=>{
               this.pagePhoto=data;
       });  
   }
```

I've imported : `import {Http} from "@angular/http";`

And passed `private http:Http` in the constructor

In my component i show img using ngFor :

```
<div *ngFor="let p of pagePhoto?.hits" class="col-md-3 ">
    <div class="panel panel-primary cadre">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{p.tags}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div>
            <p>User : {{p.user}}</p>
          </div>
          <img src="{{p.previewURL}}" >
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: remove the `.map(resp=>resp.json())` line. Make sure to open your console to see errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yout need to switch to **`HttpClient`** instead of **`Http`** also remove **`.map(resp=>resp.json())`** and code will look like,

```
this.http.get("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=10727287-66f9e40c95980a4fc92c26b12&q="+dataForm.motCle+"&per_page=5&page=1")
       .subscribe(data=>{
               this.pagePhoto=data;
 });
```

and

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/http";
```